Problema con link dinámico que descarga un PDF en vez de abrirlo
tengo un problema con un link de un archivo PDF asociado a un producto en Prestashop, el asunto es que el link al intentar abrirlo en el navegador o embeberlo como un objeto se descarga automáticamente así uno indique target="_self" así es el tipo de link:
https://xxxxx.com/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=1802

y el código que genera el link es el siguiente:
<a href="{url entity='attachment' params=['id_attachment' => $attachment.id_attachment]}" target="_self">{$attachment.name}</a>

¿Alguien tiene una idea sobre qué puedo hacer para mostrar el archivo PDF en vez de descargarlo?
Muchas gracias.

Lo de target="_self" lo agregué pensando que sería así de fácil, esto funciona sin problemas con url estáticas tipo http://xxxxx.com/archivo1.pdf pero en este caso he hecho de todo para abrir el PDF en el navegador y no lo he conseguido.

No manejo mucho PrestaShop, pero te has planteado hacer tu propio visualizador de PDFs?? La verdad no es tan complicado, solo necesitarías enviar el nombre del PDF como parámetro y listo, pero repito, no manejo mucho PrestaShop

Es buena idea, pero el tema es que tendría que hacer uno por uno los links, me tomaría muchísimo tiempo son cientos de miles de productos.

Ya tienes guardado el ID del PDF en DB eso significa que de alguna manera están enlazados, no se muestran mágicamente. Debes ver si es por ID o Nombre que se llama al PDF y en viewer instanciar ese dato. Quieres que te haga un ejemplo básico del viewrer?
